# Insert into interval observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have an observable that has some subscribers. In a defined period of time, it makes a new call to the back-end and retrieves the information. I want to be able to trigger a one-time load of data at a specified moment, get that data in that observable, but do not change the interval.

To this observable, I have some subscribers.

```
 NotificationService.notifObservable = Observable.interval(1 * 60 * 1000)
    .startWith(0)
    // merge the observable streams
    .mergeMap(res => this.http.get('ws/message/list'))
    // extract the body from the response
    .map(res => res.json())
    // use only one result
    // that is shared between subscribers
    .publishReplay()
    // converts the connectable observable to observable
    .refCount();
```

Here I want to fetch the data from the same URL and merge data in the observable above, but I don't want to change it's interval. Meaning that let's say the observable pulls data at this moment, I trigger a reload in 10 seconds and 50 seconds later, another pooling from the interval should be made. basically, I just insert data into the observables stream. How can I do that?

```
triggerNotifReload() {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that functionality merging your observable with an observable (**subject**) that when you push a value it does an http request as your ones. the code will be like this:

```
mySubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

constructor() {

    let myTriggerValueObs = this.mySubject.flatMap(() => this.http.get('ws/message/list'))


    let notifObservable = Observable.interval(1 * 60 * 1000)
        .startWith(0)
        // merge the observable streams
        .mergeMap(res => this.http.get('ws/message/list'))
        // merge wiht trigger obs
        .merge(myTriggerValueObs)
        // extract the body from the response
        .map(res => res.json())
        // use only one result
        // that is shared between subscribers
        .publishReplay()
        // converts the connectable observable to observable
        .refCount();

}

triggerNotifReload() {
    this.mySubject.next();
}
```

I Have tested the code and it works perfectly. Hope this helps.